# IntelliJ and Java/Kotlin not recognizing packages in other modules

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have the following project structure (simplified). The project is a maven project, but when working with tests I build and run the tests in IntelliJ:

```
- Main project
- -  felles
- - - src
- - - - main
- - - - - java
- - - - - - e2e.utils
- - - - - - - HelperUtils.kt

- - cucumber
- - - src
- - - - test
- - - - - java
- - - - - - e2e
- - - - - - - kontakt
- - - - - - - - KontaktSteps.kt
```

In the file HelperUtils.kt (in the felles library) I have this method (among others):

```
package e2e.utils

fun sokerSenderMeldingISaken(sakTag: String, meldingsTekst: String) {
        val response = ApiResourceFactory.eDialogResource().registrerMeldingFraSoker(
            ScenarioState.getSakId(sakTag),
            MeldingRequest.builder().meldingTO(MeldingTO.builder().melding(meldingsTekst).build())
                .innsenderTO(
                    InnsenderTO.builder().fnr(ScenarioState.getSoknad(sakTag).soknad.sokere.sokerListe[0].fnr)
                    .navn("Fleske Svarten")
                    .build()).build())
    Assert.assertEquals("Should be 200 but was " + response.statusInfo, 200, response.status.toLong())
}
```

In the file KontaktSteps.kt I'm importing the HelperUtils.kt file and using the above method:

```
import e2e.utils.*

@Når("^søkeren i \"([^\"]*)\" har sendt meldingen \"([^\"]*)\"$")
fun sokerenIHarSendtMeldingen(sakTag: String, meldingsTekst: String) {
    HelperUtils.sokerSenderMeldingISaken(sakTag, meldingsTekst)
}
```

Now, when clicking around in the KontaktSteps.kt code, the method HelperUtils is found, and I can Ctrl-click it to the source.

However, when trying to build the cucumber module (either specifically or by running up the cucumber test), IntelliJ claims

```
/<REMOVED COMPLETE PATH>/saksbehandling/e2e/cucumber/src/test/java/e2e/kontakt/KontaktSteps.kt:334:21
```

Kotlin: Unresolved reference: sokerSenderMeldingISaken

Usually, this would mean that I haven't compiled the module felles, where the HelperUtils.kt file is located. But I have, several times, but no matter what I do IntelliJ insists that the file doesn't exist. Even though it clearly "knows" it's there, since I can Ctrl-click into it.

Running "mvn clean install" works fine. It seems that IntelliJ is the problem here.

Steps I've tried:

- Rebuilt the modules, again and again, in the correct order.
- Built the whole project with maven ("mvn clean install -U")
- Invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ and rebuilt indexes and reimported all maven projects.

IntelliJ STILL insists that the method doesn't exist when building.

The strange thing is: I can still use any of the other methods in that same class, without getting any compilation errors. It's just not updating when I've added new code.

Also, if I create a new file in the same location in the felles module and compile it, I get the same problem from the cucumber project.

UPDATE:
I've also tried removing the * in the import statement, and letting IntelliJ automatically add each specific import used in the module. In case that triggered some update of refereences. Same result.

Comment: Is `felles` and `src` meant to be both at level 2, or should `src` be under `felles`?

Comment: My bad. felles and cucumber are both on the same level (under main project). src is under felles.

Comment: Cucumber Tests are processed by IDEA's native Build System and that might explain the discrepancy with Maven. Might be worth reporting this to IDEA's YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) along with a reproducer Project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, by the help of IntelliJ support.

Pretty easy: Delete or rename the system directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory

Then I reloaded the Maven project.

As to the cause, I'm pretty certain that this is due to the size and complexity of the project. Since the problem only existed internally in IntelliJ, it seems that IntelliJ was unable to keep track of the connections in the project, due to the size and complexity.